# How do red blood cells obtain energy without mitochondria?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, energy

RBCs don't have mitochondria so there is no Respiratory chain in them. But how does they get energy from Lactate. Because Lactate produce NADH which gives energy only in respiratory chain.

Comment: They do not get energy from lactate. We are pleased to welcome you to SE-Biology but expect you to do a little research before posting. Google for red cell metabolism, check Wikipedia and see what previous questions on erythrocytes have been posted here.

Comment: What process(es) do you think RBC's would need energy for, compared to the "average" cell? Does a keratinocyte need energy? Does the function of hemoglobin require energy? (These are serious questions, the answer to which I hope will help you make your question better.)